# Is there any way to make a chat discussion private?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

When.a question or answer gets heavily commented on, Stack Exchange will suggest to **convert the discussion to chat**.
The discussion then is open to everybody in chat, which is alright as others may find it helpful.

But why can't a commenter delete such a chat message, while (s)he had the full right to do so when they were comments?

Why can't the asker delete the chat room, while (s)he has the privilege to delete the question?

I've researched about sending a private message and continue the discussion further, but it was suggested that we have to view the profile and send a message on email, social media, or whatever provided there.

So, as mentioned: Should we have to use email to continue a private discussion and send the question's links, introduce first, and say I want to continue the discussion started in the comments?
Or is there another option?

***NOTE: This may be eligible for duplication because there are lots of discussion already in the topic which I've also seen, but I didn't find anything answering my question.***

Comment: @DeerHunter Only moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: @Yannis - yep, my fault. I stand corrected. "They just require higher privileges to see".

Comment: There's no private message system... SE isn't a social site, so everything is public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't delete things in chat without the privileges - but why do you need to?

The system suggests moving to chat so that a comment thread doesn't get interminably long, and discourage others from using the comment for asking for clarifications or suggesting improvements. However, a link to the chatroom is left in the comment thread because the contents of discussion around the post can often be useful, and others may want to see it.

There's no reason you should resort to making everything super private, unless the discussion should by its nature be private - in which case you should not be having it in the comments in the first place.

Leave the chat history around, because it might be useful to someone else.

---

*N.B. If you* really *need something deleted from chat, you can either drop into [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) chat room and ask for it (a mod will follow up) or use a chat moderator flag to ask for deletion. If you've posted truly private information, always use a flag and request a history purge.*